# Html5shiv library from Bootstrap 3.1.1 Not Working in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap 3.1.1 in my web page and add html5shiv lib and respond lib for fix it this but it is not worked on internet explorer 8.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!--[if IE]>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">

 <div class="header_wrapper">

     <div class="top_bar_wrapper">
          <div class="container">
               <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                         First Column
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                         Second Column
                    </div>

               </div>
          </div>
     </div>

 </div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot : IE 8 Screenshot 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYxLW.jpg

[image: IE 8 Screenshot]

Mozilla Screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfNyo.jpg

[image: Mozilla Screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

Are you viewing your page using the file:// protocol? In your screenshot it looks like you are, but its a little hard to see for sure...

From the [Boostrap Docs on Respond.js and IE8:](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-respondjs)

> Due to browser security rules, Respond.js doesn't work with pages viewed via the file:// protocol (like when opening a local HTML file). To test responsive features in IE8, view your pages over HTTP(S). See the Respond.js docs for details.

You have to view your pages using the http(s) protocol for this to work correctly. On windows you can use IIS or IIS Express to create a local web server and test your pages using http(s) protocol. Or there are many other free options for this (Google is your friend).